# Group formatting in Telerik

Tags: telerik, telerik-reporting

Currently, I'm generating a report in Telerik that has 2 groups: Name and Date. Now, in the footer of each group, I have a line to show the distinction between group sets. Here's what it looks like:

[image: Current grouping]

As you can see, the Red Group 1 and Blue Group 2 are functioning as they should. My problem is that the footer line shows up for Blue Group 2 when it should only show the line for Red Group 1. I've tried to reorganize my groups, tried to use a conditional formatting, but nothing seems to work out. Is there another way to get this to work the way I need and look the way I need? Intended look is below:

[image: Intended grouping]

Comment: Isn't this like grouped by name ordered by date?

If so you need only one group and the unwonted line probem should disappear.
For better readibility you can apply alterante row colors.

Comment: @FeliceM: Sadly, it's not that simple. I need to have the line seperating the date grouping, too. This is for a client who was very specific with what they want.

Answer (score 0):

I actually just solved this using some conditional formatting on the Group 2 line itself. I did a check to see if it was the last row of the group using the primary field of the group (in this case, Gift Date), and if so, set the visibility to false.